# UIPickerView didSelectRow not called

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, swift, uipickerview

(Swift, Xcode6, iOS8, iPhone)

In my `UIPickerView` control, `didSelectRow` is not being called.

- Yes, I have set `Splash` as the delegate (and datasource) for the picker.
- `Splash` extends the `UIViewController` class
- All the other functions work. No errors, the picker spins, has five rows, and displays the row number as defined in the other functions.

When does the `didSelectRow` method get called? Do I need to implement a `Done` button of some kind, or will this method fire when the user stops spinning? Do I need to implement a separate notification? tyvm :)

```
class Splash: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var countryPicker : UIPickerView = nil

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String {
    return "\(row)"

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    println("Row: \(row)")
    return row
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong signature, `pickerView:didSelectRow:forComponent:` returns void, not an integer.  Try:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) {
    println("Row: \(row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
print("selected row = \(row)") }
```